# C++ char arithmetic overflow

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a = 30;
    char b = 40;
    char c = 10;
    printf ("%d ", char(a*b));
    char d = (a * b) / c;
    printf ("%d ", d);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code yields normal int value if `127 > x > -127`
and a overflow value if other. I can't understand how the overflow value is calculated. As -80 in this case.
Thanks

Comment: Signed type overflow is undefined behaviour, so the result may be whatever, including a whale falling on your house.

Comment: 30*40=1200 there overflow...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Curiously enough, the only thing that went through the mind of the bowl of petunias as it fell was Oh no, not again.

Comment: You might want to pick a different datatype to work with.  Since `char` can be signed or unsigned on some implementations this is defined behavior and on others this is undefined behavior.

Comment: your code doesn't compile because of the weird line with char(a*b)

Comment: It's compiling fine though, I read this question in a code/output question, so what you guys are saying that on an overflow, system can output any value ?

Comment: NO, it will not compile.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Oh.. 'I read this question in a code/output question' - please say that you compiled it OK before posting it....

Comment: Dev C++, GCC compiler

Comment: He probably compile it as C++. It is valid C++, but not valid C

Comment: *The implementation shall define `char` to have the same range, representation, and behaviour as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`. [...] Irrespective of the choice made, `char` is a separate type from the other two and is not compatible with either.* -- ISO/IEC 9899:2011, "Programming Languages -- C". **Do not use `char` for arithmetics, *ever*.** If you *must* use a type with `sizeof T == 1`, use `signed char` or `unsigned char`, explicitly.

Comment: I wasn't using it any arithmetic. I read this question in a code/output post. I just wanted to know, how the overflow was being calculated.

Comment: Hard to say because `char` can be either signed or unsigned. To explain it in C you first need to convert 30*40 to `unsigned int` then convert it to `signed char`, the you can explain everything with 1) integer promotion before multiplication, 2) `signed int` to `unsigned int` conversion, 3) `unsigned int` to `signed char` conversion of the product, 4) integer promotion when passed to `%d` of printf. Directly convert `30*40` to `char` is UB and also depends on `char` being signed and unsigned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick here is how numbers are represented. Look into [2's complement](http://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/). 30 * 40 in binary is 1200 or 10010110000 base 2. But our char is only 8 bits so we chop off the leading 100 (and all the implied 0s before that). This leaves us with `1011000`.

Note the leading 1. In 2s complement, how your computer probably stores the values, this indicates a negative number. `11111111` is -1, `11111110` is -2 and so on. If go down to 1011000 we get to -80.

That is, if we convert 1011000 to 2s complement we're left with -80.

You can do 2s complement by hand. Take the value, drop the leading sign bit and swap the other values. In this case `10110000` turns into `01001111` in binary this would be 79. Turn it negative and remove one more because we don't start at zero and we're at -80.

Comment: How do we know that we have to " chop off the leading 100 (and all the implied 0s before that) " ?

Comment: Isn't converting signed int to smaller type UB when the value can be represented by the smaller type?

Comment: @NikhilVerma we don't know it. This is what actually happens here, but something else might happen as well. It's UB.

Comment: a char is usually 8-bits. So we chop off all except the last 8 bits. sizeof(char) will give you the number of bytes a type takes up. It's likely to be 1. As noted over and underflow and undefined, but the above is probably what is actually happening

Answer (score 1):

Char has only 1 byte. In this case 1200 is 0100 1011 0000 (binary).
For one byte you can only assign 8 bit, in your case: 1011 0000 (first 4 bits will be deleted). Now you have -80 (first bit shows if negative (1) or positive (0)).
Try with your calculator (programmer) and type 1200 decimal and switch from Qword to Byte and you can see what happens with your number.